# Regex or substring operation to strip out a URL from a keyword onwards

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to figure out the best way to strip out all the content in a URL from a specific keyword onwards (including the keyword), using either regex or a substring operation. So if I have an example dynamic URL `http://example.com/category/subcat/filter/size/1/` - I would like to strip out the /filter/size/1 element of the URL and leave me with the remaining URL as a separate string. Grateful for any pointers. I should clarify that the number of arguments after the `filter` keyword isn't fixed and could be more than in my example *and* the number of category arguments prior to the `filter` keyword isn't fixed either

Comment: `'http://example.com/category/subcat/filter/size/1/'.replace(/^.*filter\/size\/1/, '')` try [regex101.com](https://regex101.com).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split()` function.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

```js
url='http://example.com/category/subcat/filter/size/1/';
console.log(url.split('/filter')[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that won't catch variable nested levels of subcategories - e.g http://example.com/category/subcat/subsubcat/filter/size/1/color/black - sorry i should have clarified that in the OP

Comment: This splits on a word.

Comment: @bsod99 What kind of URL do you expect with subcategories?

Answer (score 0):

To be a little safer you could use the `URL` object to handle most of the parsing and then
just sanitize the `pathname`.

```js
const filteredUrl = 'http://example.com/category/subcat/filter/test?param1&param2=test';

console.log(unfilterUrl(filteredUrl));

function unfilterUrl(urlString) {
  const url = new URL(urlString);
  url.pathname = url.pathname.replace(/(?<=\/)filter(\/|$).*/i, '');
  return url.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak this a little based on your need. Like it might be the case where `filter` is not present in the URL. but lets assume it is present then consider the following regex expression.

`/(.*)\/filter\/(.*)/g`

the first captured group ( can be obtained by `$1` ) is the portion of the string behind the `filter` keyword and the second captured group ( obtained by `$2` ) will contain all your filters present after the `filter` keyword

have a look at example i tried on `regextester.com`
[image: regex tester]

Answer (score 0):

## Split

The simplest solution that occurs to me is the following:

```js
const url = 'http://example.com/category/subcat/filter/size/1/';
const [base, filter] = url.split('/filter/');

// where:
// base == 'http://example.com/category/subcat'
// filter == 'size/1/'
```

If you expect more than one occurrence of `'/filter/'`, use the limit parameter of `String.split()`: `url.split('/filter/', 2);`

## RegExp

The assumption of the above is that after the `filter` parameter, everything is part of the filter. If you need more granularity, you can use a regex that terminates at the `'?'`, for example. This will remove everything from `'filter/anything/that/follows'` that immediately follows a `/` and until the first query string separator `?`, not including.

```js
const filterRegex = /(?<=\/)filter(\/|$)[^?]*/i;

function parseURL(url) {
    const match = url.match(filterRegex);
    if (!match) { return [url, null, null]; } // expect anything

    const stripped = url.replace(filterRegex, '');
    return [url, stripped, match[0]];
}

const [full, stripped, filter] = parseURL('http://example.com/category/subcat/filter/size/1/?query=string');

// where:
// stripped == 'http://example.com/category/subcat/?query=string'
// filter == 'filter/size/1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sadly not able to post the full answer here, as i'ts telling me 'it looks like spam'. I created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/KilianKilmister/8ccb0c7500ea70580f0e956be4eea98c) with the original answer. In it i talk about the details of `String.prototype.match` and of JS/ES regex in general including named capture groups and pitfalls. And incude a link to a great regex tool: `regex101`. I'm not posting the link here in fear of triggering the filter again. But back to the topic:

In short, a simple regext can be used to split and format it (using `filter` as the keyword):

- `/^(.*)(\/filter\/.*)$/`

or with named groups:

- `/^(?<main>.*)(?<stripped>\/filter\/.*)$/`

(note that the forward slashes need to be escaped in a regex literal)

Using `String.prototype.match` with that regex will return an array of the matches: index 1 will be the first capture group (so everything before the keyword), index 2 will be everything after that (including the keyword).

Again, all the details can be found in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/KilianKilmister/8ccb0c7500ea70580f0e956be4eea98c)